# Парсинг времени входа аккаунтов

Tags: python, парсер, python-3.9

Код собирает данные о последних 100 людях, которые воошли в сообщество. Получает имя, айди, фото и дату создания. Преобразует дату создания аккаунта в datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 25, 3, 3, 38) и добавляет в массив. В приложении есть ботосети, которые входят в сообщество по 100 штук за 10 секунд. Как мне имея данные о времени входа различать. К примеру вошло 50 аккаунтов за 10 секунд - начинается алгоритм бана их по userId

```
from datetime import datetime as TimeParser
from datetime import timedelta as addTime

def bann(subclient):

    pattern = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
    maxint = 5 # Это значение используется для определения времени ботнета на 100 участников, в данном случае бот сработает, если вступит 100 или более участников за 5 секунд

    while True:

        timeList = []

        try:

            users = subclient.get_all_users(size=100).profile

            for name, userId, icon, cTime in zip(users.nickname, users.userId, users.icon, users.createdTime):

                timeList.append(TimeParser.strptime(cTime, pattern))
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: То есть если в это же время что и боты в сообщество зайдёт живой человек, вы его тоже забаните? Ну, он же в это же время зашёл.

Comment: Если забанится 1-2 человека во время захода ботов это лучшее решение, нежели сообщество атакует 5 тысяч ботов и вызовут нестабильную работу